# Using Pandas: How do I combine multiple rows of data into a single row based on a common key?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by, merge

## Need help merging multiple rows of data with various datatypes for multiple columns

I have a dataframe that contains 14 columns and x number of rows of data. An example slice of the dataframe is linked below:

Current Example of my dataframe

[image: Current Example of my dataframe]

I want to be able to merge all four rows of data into a single row based on the "work order" column. See linked image below. I am currently using pandas to take data from four different data sources and create a dataframe that has all the relevant data I want based on each work order number. I have tried various methods including groupby, merge, join, and others without any good results.

How I want my dataframe to look in the end

[image: How I want my dataframe to look in the end]

I essentially want to groupby the work order value, merge all the site names into a single value, then have all data essentially condense to a single row. If there is identical data in a column then I just want it to merge together. If there are values in a column that are different (such as in "Operator Ack Timestamp") then I don't mind the data being a continuous string of data (ex. one date after the next within the same cell).

example dataframe data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Work Order': [10025,10025,10025,10025],
                   'Site': ['SC1', 'SC1', 'SC1', 'SC1'],
                   'Description_1':['','','Inverter 10A-1 - No Comms',''],
                   'Description_2':['','','Inverter 10A-1 - No Comms',''],
                   'Description_3':['Inverter 10A-1 has lost communications.','','',''],
                   'Failure Type':['','','Communications',''],
                   'Failure Class':['','','2',''],
                   'Start of Fault':['','','2021-05-30 06:37:00',''],
                   'Operator Ack Timestamp':['2021-05-30 8:49:21','','2021-05-30 6:47:57',''],
                   'Timestamp of Notification':['2021-05-30 07:18:58','','',''],
                   'Actual Start Date':['','2021-05-30 6:37:00','','2021-05-30 6:37:00'],
                   'Actual Start Time':['','06:37:00','','06:37:00'],
                   'Actual End Date':['','2021-05-30 08:24:00','',''],
                   'Actual End Time':['','08:24:00','','']})

df.head()
```

Comment: Please include samples of data as text, not images, so that people can actually use them. This [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) might help.

Comment: @joao 
just added the dataframe data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 steps to get expected output:

1. Replace empty values by [`pd.NA`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#missing-data-na),
2. Group your data by `Work Order` column because it seems to be the index key,
3. For each group, fill `NA` value by last valid observation and keep the last record,
4. Reset index to have the same format as input.

<s>I choose to group by "Work Order" because it seems to be the index key of your dataframe.</s>
The index of your dataframe is "Work Order":

```
df = df.set_index("Work Order")
```

````
out = df.replace({'': pd.NA}) \
        .groupby("Work Order", as_index=False) \
        .apply(lambda x: x.ffill().tail(1)) \
        .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)```
````

```
>>> out.T  # transpose for better vizualisation
Work Order                                                   10025
Site                                                           SC1
Description_1                            Inverter 10A-1 - No Comms
Description_2                            Inverter 10A-1 - No Comms
Description_3              Inverter 10A-1 has lost communications.
Failure Type                                        Communications
Failure Class                                                    2
Start of Fault                                 2021-05-30 06:37:00
Operator Ack Timestamp                          2021-05-30 6:47:57
Timestamp of Notification                      2021-05-30 07:18:58
Actual Start Date                               2021-05-30 6:37:00
Actual Start Time                                         06:37:00
Actual End Date                                2021-05-30 08:24:00
Actual End Time                                           08:24:00
```

Comment: I added an example dataframe above to the original question if that helps.

Comment: To save to an excel file, you can use `out.to_excel('FileLocation.xlsx', index=False)`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. In the larger dataframe that this slice of data came from, I have the "work order" column set as the index.  So I removed the last part of your code >>> .reset_index(drop=True)  <<< and it displays a double index for "work order." I originally tried just changing True to False in the reset index portion of the code, but got an argument error. Any ideas on preventing a double index but maintaining "work order" as an index?

Comment: I updated my answer to take into account your last comment.

Comment: if I wanted the columns "Actual Start Date" and "Actual Start Time" to display the earliest date how would I go about doing that? Let's say I want "6/5/21 1:35:00" to be the output value in the final "grouped-by" row at the end assuming the two available input values were 6/5/21 1:35:00 and 6/7/21 5:23:00 in that column index? Could you pass an argument to make sure the lowest date is displayed?